# The non-abstract class 'AppDatabase' is missing implementations for these members

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-moor, moor

Trying to get my HelloWorld app running in Flutter for the first time. I've hit an error that I can't Google my way out of. When running `flutter run`, I get the following error, and there is nothing listed (no members):

```
Error (Xcode): lib/database.dart:116:7: 
Error: The non-abstract class 'AppDatabase' is missing implementations for these members:
```

Here's the code around line 116:

```
@UseMoor(tables: [Users, Games, Groups, GroupMembers, Leaderboards, UserGameStatus])
116> class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
  // Define the constructor
  AppDatabase(QueryExecutor e) : super(e);

  // Custom SQL statements for index creation
  Future<void> createIndexes() async {
    await customStatement('CREATE INDEX idx_leaderboard_rank ON leaderboards (rank);');
    await customStatement('CREATE INDEX idx_leaderboard_user_id ON leaderboards (user_id);');
  }
...
```

All of the tables are defined above this block. I don't know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated. I have run the various clean functions:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub run build_runner clean
flutter pub run build_runner build
flutter run
```

And `flutter doctor` looks good.

The file `database.g.dart` is getting generated but I don't know what to look for in there.

Here is the code of `pubspec.yaml` and the complete `database.dart` file, and `main.dart`:

`pubspec.yaml`

```
name: MyApp
description: HelloWorld

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.1.3"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  moor:
  path_provider:
  path:
  provider:
  sqlite3_flutter_libs:

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts:
  moor_generator:

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

`main.dart`

```
// main.dart //

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/custom_header.dart'; // Import your custom header widget
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'database.dart'; // Import your database code
import 'homepage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => DatabaseProvider(database),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              // Username field
              TextFormField(
                controller: usernameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Username',
                  // You can add other styling or icons here
                ),
              ),
              // Password field
              TextFormField(
                controller: passwordController,
                obscureText: true, // Hide the password
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  // You can add other styling or icons here
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16), // Spacer for separation
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final username = usernameController.text;

                  // Check if the user exists
                  final user = await context.read<DatabaseProvider>().getUser(username);

                  if (user != null) {
                    // User exists, you can proceed with authentication logic
                    // You may also want to navigate to the home page here
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => HomePage(user: user)
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    // User does not exist, show an error message or handle as needed
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Login Error'),
                          content: Text('User does not exist.'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text('OK'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Login/Register'),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up controllers
    usernameController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

and finally

`database.dart`

```
// database.dart //

import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Column, Table;
import 'package:moor/moor.dart';

part 'database.g.dart';

final database = AppDatabase(QueryExecutor(databaseFactoryFfi.openDatabase('my.db')));

// Define a DatabaseProvider class to manage database access
class DatabaseProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final AppDatabase _database;

  DatabaseProvider(this._database);

  Future<UserWithoutPassword?> getUser(String username) async {
    final query = select(_database.users)..where((user) => user.username.equals(username));
    final userData = await query.getSingleOrNull();

    if (userData != null) {
      return UserWithoutPassword(
        userId: userData.userId,
        username: userData.username,
        email: userData.email,
        createdAt: userData.createdAt,
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isGameStarted(AppDatabase database) async {
    final now = DateTime.now(); // Get the current date/time

    // Query to check if a game for the current user has started
    final query = select(database.userGameStatus)
      ..where((status) => status.userId.equals(widget.user.userId))
      ..where((status) => status.startDate.isSmallerThanValue(now))
      ..limit(1); // Limit to 1 result

    final result = await query.get();

    // If there is at least one game that has started, return true; otherwise, return false
    return result.isNotEmpty;
  }

  // Add more methods for other database operations here

  // You can also create methods to update data and notify listeners if needed
}

class UserWithoutPassword {
  final int userId;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final DateTime createdAt;

  UserWithoutPassword({
    required this.userId,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.createdAt,
  });
}

// Define tables and columns
@DataClassName('User')
class Users extends Table {
  IntColumn get userId => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get username => text().customConstraint('UNIQUE')();
  TextColumn get email => text().customConstraint('UNIQUE')();
  TextColumn get password => text()();
  DateTimeColumn get createdAt => dateTime().customConstraint('DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL')();
}

class Games extends Table {
  IntColumn get gameId => integer().autoIncrement()();
  DateTimeColumn get startDate => dateTime()();
  DateTimeColumn get endDate => dateTime()();
  BoolColumn get isActive => boolean().customConstraint('DEFAULT true NOT NULL')();
}

class Groups extends Table {
  IntColumn get groupId => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get groupName => text()();
  IntColumn get createdByUserId => integer()();
  DateTimeColumn get createdAt => dateTime().customConstraint('DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL')();
}

class GroupMembers extends Table {
  IntColumn get groupMemberId => integer().autoIncrement()();
  IntColumn get groupId => integer()();
  IntColumn get userId => integer()();
}

@DataClassName('Leaderboard')
class Leaderboards extends Table {
  IntColumn get leaderboardId => integer().autoIncrement()();
  IntColumn get userId => integer().customConstraint('REFERENCES users(user_id)')();
  IntColumn get gameId => integer().customConstraint('REFERENCES games(game_id)')();
  IntColumn get groupId => integer().customConstraint('REFERENCES groups(group_id)')();
  IntColumn get rank => integer()();
}

@DataClassName('UserGameState')
class UserGameStatus extends Table {
  IntColumn get userGameStatusId => integer().autoIncrement()();
  IntColumn get userId => integer()();
  IntColumn get gameId => integer()();
  DateTimeColumn get startDate => dateTime()();
  DateTimeColumn get endDate => dateTime()();
  BoolColumn get isAlive => boolean().customConstraint('DEFAULT true NOT NULL')();
}

@UseMoor(tables: [Users, Games, Groups, GroupMembers, Leaderboards, UserGameStatus])
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
  // Define the constructor
  AppDatabase(QueryExecutor e) : super(e);

  // Custom SQL statements for index creation
  Future<void> createIndexes() async {
    await customStatement('CREATE INDEX idx_leaderboard_rank ON leaderboards (rank);');
    await customStatement('CREATE INDEX idx_leaderboard_user_id ON leaderboards (user_id);');
  }

  // Custom SQL statements for trigger creation
  Future<void> createTriggers() async {
    await customStatement('''
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_leaderboard()
      RETURNS TRIGGER AS \$
      BEGIN
        -- Check if a player's is_alive status changes to false
        IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND NEW.is_alive = false THEN
          INSERT INTO leaderboards (user_id, game_id, group_id, wins, rank)
          SELECT
            NEW.user_id,
            NEW.game_id,
            gm.group_id,
            COUNT(*) AS wins,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NEW.game_id, gm.group_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rank
          FROM
            user_game_status AS ugs
          INNER JOIN
            group_members AS gm
          ON
            ugs.user_id = gm.user_id
          WHERE
            ugs.game_id = NEW.game_id
            AND ugs.is_alive = false
          GROUP BY
            NEW.user_id, NEW.game_id, gm.group_id;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
      \$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    ''');

    await customStatement('''
      CREATE TRIGGER game_completion_trigger
      AFTER UPDATE ON user_game_status
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE FUNCTION update_leaderboard();
    ''');
  }

}
```

Also, since I'm new to this, any feedback on structure/style would be helpful but mostly I'm stuck on this one error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. What are the missing members?  Can you add them?  2. It looks like `moor` and `moor_generator` packages have been discontinued and replaced with the [`drift`](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) and [`drift_dev`](https://pub.dev/packages/drift_dev) packages respectively.    It will be easier to help you if you switch to those since they will have more up-to-date documentation.

Comment: @jamesdlin There are no missing members listed, which is frustrating. I will see what I can do about moor/drift, but the docs I'm trying to use to learn aren't that up to date, so I've been using moor in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you will want to update the `moor` package however, the `moor` has been renamed to drift and the `moor` package discontinued. Its been advised to to migrate to `drift`.

Consider switching to `drift` and updating your code to match then try again.